# How to stop flickering of RecyclerView in Adapter after onResume() and onPause()?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, onresume, onpause

I have a chat application that uses RecyclerView to store the chats. The chat contains images and texts. It uses Firebase Database to store and retrieve data. Also, I have stored the user's current status (online/offline). The user's current status is displayed in the toolbar. The onResume() method sets the user status to "online" and onPause() method sets the user status to "offline". Every time a user changes its status, the whole Recycler View flickers on the other user's UI.

[Message Activity Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbr5B.jpg)

So, here if I am messaging the user and if that user changes its status to online or offline (displayed in the toolbar), the images flicker. And also, if I scroll up to view the previous messages and in the meantime, if the user changes its status, the RecyclerView automatically scrolls to the last.

How do I stop the flickering and the automatic scrolling of the messages when the user changes its status?

I tried to disable animations of RecyclerView using ItemAnimator but that didn't work. I can't figure out if this is the problem of the RecyclerView or using the Glide library.
This is the code for getting the values from the database.

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

     databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
             username.setText(user.getName());
             if(user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
                 profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
             } else {
                 Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageURL()).into(profile_image);
             }
             if(user.getStatus().equals("online")){
                 status.setText("online");
             }else{
                 status.setText("offline");
             }
             readMessages(fuser.getUid(), userid, user.getImageURL());
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

         }
     });
```

This is the code for how the status are switched.

```
private void status(String status){
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(fuser.getUid());
    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("status", status);
    databaseReference.updateChildren(hashMap);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    status("online");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    status("offline");
}
```

And this is the recyclerview which flickers everytime the status is changed.

```
private void readMessages(final String myid, final String userid, final String imageURL){
    mChats = new ArrayList<>();

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats").child(myid).child(userid);
    databaseReference.keepSynced(true);
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mChats.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Chat chats = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

                if(chats.getReceiver().equals(myid) && chats.getSender().equals(userid) ||
                        chats.getReceiver().equals(userid) && chats.getSender().equals(myid))
                    mChats.add(chats);
            }
            messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this, mChats, imageURL);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// avoid flickering of the recyclerview

```
((SimpleItemAnimator) myRecyclerview.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
```

or

```
myRecyclerview.setItemAnimator(null);
```

do this as soon as you initialize myRecyclerview